# Finding missing dates compared to date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table (A) with date ranges and another (B) with just a set date.  There are missing months in B that are within the date range of A.  I need to identify the missing months.
A

```
Person StartDate EndDate  
123    1/1/2016  5/1/2016
```

B

```
Person EffectiveDate  
123    1/1/2016  
123    2/1/2016  
123    4/1/2016  
123    5/1/2016  

Expected result would be  
123    3/1/2016
```

I'm using SQL Server 2012.  Any assistance would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You can join to a CTE of month numbers

Comment: What determines the month? If table A has a StartDate of 04/01/2016 and EndDate of 07/01/2016, is there supposed to be a record for each month from 04 - 07?

Comment: Hi Kramb.  Yes, there is supposed to be an entry for every month but I need to find the missing months.  Of course there are also thousands of records in each table for different person records.  It would be similar to finding a missed payment during a time period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to generate all values between the two dates.  Here is an approach using a numbers table:

```
with n as (
      select row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as n
      from master.spt_values
     )
select a.person, dateadd(day, n.n, a.startdate) as missingdate
from a join
     n
     on dateadd(day, n.n, a.startdate) <= day.enddate left join
     b
     on b.person = a.person and b.effectivedate = dateadd(day, n.n, a.startdate)
where b.person is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #A (Person INT, StartDate DATE, EndDate  DATE)

INSERT INTO #A

SELECT '123','1/1/2016',  '5/1/2016'

CREATE TABLE #B(Person INT, EffectiveDate  DATE)

INSERT INTO #B
SELECT 123 ,'1/1/2016' UNION ALL  
SELECT 123 ,'2/1/2016' UNION ALL  
SELECT 123 ,'4/1/2016' UNION ALL  
SELECT 123 ,'5/1/2016'


;WITH A1
AS(
    SELECT PERSON , StartDate, EndDate 
    FROM #A

    UNION ALL

    SELECT PERSON ,DATEADD(MM,1,STARTDATE), EndDate 
    FROM A1
    WHERE DATEADD(MM,1,STARTDATE) <= EndDate 
)
SELECT PERSON , StartDate
FROM A1
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS
(
 SELECT 1 FROM #B B1 
 WHERE B1.Person = A1.PERSON 
 AND YEAR(B1.EffectiveDate) = YEAR(A1.STARTDATE) AND MONTH(B1.EffectiveDate) = MONTH(A1.STARTDATE) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you are interested in getting missing months

```
;WITH n
     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY
                                 (
                                     SELECT NULL
                                 )) - 1 AS n
         FROM master.dbo.spt_values)
     SELECT a.person,
            DATEADD(MONTH, n.n, a.startdate) AS missingdate
     FROM a a
          INNER JOIN n ON DATEADD(MONTH, n.n, a.startdate) <= a.enddate
          LEFT JOIN b b ON MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, n.n, a.startdate)) = MONTH(b.effectivedate) AND YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, n.n, a.startdate)) = YEAR(b.effectivedate)
     WHERE b.person IS NULL;
```